# mongofiles gridfs put file with metadata

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I would like to put some extra metadata along with my input file when using mongofiles to put the data into my gridfs mongodb, I cannot find any official documents regarding this question. Please help!

The current command i am using is
`mongofiles --uri mongodb://172.21.65.208:20007 -d gridfs -r put "{new_pbf_file_name}"`

Or are there any alternatives like using pymongo put the local file into the gridfs?

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing anything in the documentation or source code for mongofiles that looks like metadata support.

You can request this functionality via https://feedback.mongodb.com/ if you like.

Comment: thank you, cuz I can't find any docs regarding uploading metadata too. I will post a request later, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can update metadata in other script by mongoshell

mongo uri script.js

#### script

```
var bulkFsFiles = db.fs.files.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

var metadata = {
    "_contentType" : "application/pdf",
    "_class" : "com.mongodb.BasicDBObject"
}

bulkFsFiles.find({
    '_id': 'id'
}).update(
    {
        $set: {
            'metadata': metadata
        }
    }
)

print(bulkFsFiles.execute());
```